# How should I organize common linq queries (or even SQL queries)?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, entity-framework

I use the Entity Framework. Let's say I have a realy complex linq query, that I need in multiple parts of my application, some services, some controllers.

Is there any design pattern I should follow?

First I thought, the Repository Pattern would perfectly be valid:

```
MyDto myRepository.GetDataFromComplexQuery();
```

But we shouldn't use the [Repository Pattern with Entity Framework](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180851/why-shouldnt-i-use-the-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework). The answer in the linked question is talking about using Services instead. However, I don't want to boil my service classes with a lot of (duplicating) complex query logic.

So I am wondering how I should design this and how to organize it in the solution?

Something like this feels very wrong:

```
namespace Foo.Data.DataHelpers
{
    public class ComplexQuery
    {
        private DbContext _ctx;

        public ComplexQuery(DbContext ctx)
        {
            _ctx = ctx;
        }

        public MyDto GetData()
        {
            query = //...
            return query.Single();
        }
    }
}
```

Also sometimes the query is to complex and needs to replaced by plain old SQL for performance reason. But I don't think, this would change the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by "service pattern" [the answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/220126/274599) is recommending you use an interface that abstracts the source of the data. It differs from the repository pattern in that the repository pattern is an abstraction that models a data source as if it were a collection with operations for listing, updating, and creating new elements. Whereas services abstract the actions required by the client in a request-response approach. The naming of the service would depend on the purpose of the queries, and you would group similar queries under the same service. In the following example I use the domain of report building as a domain that requires some complex queries.

```
interface IReportDataService {
  MyDto getReportData();
} 

public class DbReportDataService : IReportDataService {
  private DbContext _ctx;

  public DbReportDataService(DbContext ctx) {
    _ctx = ctx;
  }

  MyDto IReportDataService.getReportData() {
    query = //...
    return query.Single();
  }
}

// Usage
public class ReportBuilder {
  private IReportDataService _dataService;

  public ReportBuilder(IReportDataService dataService) {
    _dataService = dataService;
  }

  public Report fillReport(...) {
    MyDto data = _dataService.getReportData();
  }
}
```

By using this abstraction, you can unit test `ReportBuilder` by mocking 
`IReportDataService`. The implementation can use Linq or SQL scripts--it doesn't matter to `ReportBuilder`. Your [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) should construct a single instance of `DbReportDataService` and inject it into components that need it (`ReportBuilder`).