# Should Entity Framework 6 not be used with repository pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, entity-framework, orm, repository-pattern

So I am asking this after reading the following: [Why shouldn't I use the repository pattern with Entity Framework?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180851/why-shouldnt-i-use-the-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework/220126).

It seems there is a large split of people who say yay and those that say nay. What seems to be missing from some of the answers are concrete examples, whether that be `code` or good reasoning or whatever.

The issue is I keep reading people responding saying "well EF is already abstraction". Well that's great, and that's probably true, but then how would you use it without the repository pattern?

For those that say otherwise, why would you say otherwise, what personally have you run into that made is necessary?

Comment: I've shared my thoughts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180501/what-specific-issue-does-the-repository-pattern-solve/13189143#13189143), but I think EF is perfectly fine when used as the data access mechanism of a repository.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To get this out of the way, I am a big proponent of Entity Framework, but it does come with some drawbacks that you need to be aware of.

I also apologize for the long answer, but this is a very hot topic with many opinions and many required considerations. For small application, a lot of these considerations don't matter, but for enterprise-grade applications they do matter a lot.

Part of what makes the EF discussion such a hot topic is that it leads to a chain of events, where each solution introduces a new problem (which sometimes only applies in more advanced cases). If I just gave you the final (or should I say current) answer, you'd think that I was omitting several other solutions, so I think it's relevant to walk you through the solutions and how they are not the final solution to the problem.

---

### Repositories

> how would you use it without the repository pattern?

The short answer to that is that (simple) repositories are an **anti-pattern*** to Entity Framework.

EF provides a context, which essentially provides access to the whole database. You can e.g. fire a query that returns all Country entities with their Province entities already filled in, with each province's City entities already filled in. In short, it enables to you execute multiple-entity-type queries (this is a phrase I coined myself in order to explain the difference with repositories).

Repositories, at least the basic implementation thereof, tend to take a "one entity type per repository" approach. If you want to get a list of all countries with all their provinces and all of the province's cities, you'll have to separately talk to the `CountryRepository`, `ProviceRepository` and `CityRepository`. In short, repositories limit you to only being able to execute single-entity-type queries. For the same example, you would have to launch 3 separate database queries in order to get all countries and their provinces and their cities.

And don't get me wrong, I like repositories. I like having the neat little boxes so you can separate your storage of different domain objects, which e.g. would allow you to get the countries from your database but the provinces from a remote API and the cities for a second remote API.

But this separation of entity types into their own private boxes very much clashes with the benefit of having relational databases, where part of the benefit is that you can launch a single query that can take related entities into account (for filtering, sorting or returning).

You might rightly respond that *"a repository can still return more than one entity type"*. And you would be correct. But if you have a query which returns both `Foo` and `Bar` entities, where do you place it? In the `FooRepository`? In the `BarRepository`? There may be examples where the choice is easy, but there are also examples where the choice is hard and multiple developers may have different categorization methods and thus the codebase becomes inconsistent and the true purpose of the "one entity type per repository" approach will be thrown out the window.

---

**When I say repositories are an anti-pattern, that is not a global statement, but rather than they specifically counteract the purpose of EF. Without EF or a similar solution, repositories are not an anti-pattern.*

---

### Query objects

Query objects are the only real way to get around the "one entity type per repository" approach. The shortest way I can describe what a query object is, is that you should think of it as a "one method repository".

Repositories suffer from having to deal with multiple types of entities, and the more methods a repository has, the more distinct entity types it's likely going to be handling. By separating each repository method into a query object of its own, you've simply removed the contradictory suggestion that "this repository only handles one type", and instead are suggesting that "this query object runs this particular query, regardless of which entity types it needs to use".

You can still use repositories at the same time, and you are then able to **enforce** that repositories will never handle more than their designated entity type.

- If a query makes use of more than one entity type (e.g. `Country` and `Province`), then it belongs in its own private query object (e.g. `CountriesAndTheirProvincesQuery`).
- If a query only focuses on one entity type (e.g. `Country`), then it belongs to that entity type's repository (e.g. `CountryRepository`).

On a technical level, query objects work exactly like repositories do. The only difference is that you separate the logic differently by no longer trying to pretend that your multi-entity-type queries belong to a single-entity-type repository.

---

### Repositories 2

There is a second problem pertaining to repositories. As they are separate classes, they do not depend on each other. This usually also means that each repository will use their own EF context (I'm omitting dependency injection here as it sidetracks the focus of the answer).

Suppose you are doing an import, which adds countries and cities to the database. However, you want transactional safety, meaning that when *any* failure is encountered, then *nothing* should be saved to the database.
But when you have to deal with two repositories that each have their own context, how can you knowingly call `SaveChanges()` on one context before knowing that the other context's `SaveChanges()` succeeded? You're going to have to guess, and you're going to be stuck manually undoing the first context's commit when the second context's commit ends up failing.

By separating the repositories, you've removed their ability to have a *shared* context, which you need in times where you're dealing with transactions that operate on more than one entity type at the same time.

---

### Unit of work

In any sufficiently large codebase or domain where I've used repositories and EF, I've ended up implementing a unit of work to at least somewhat counter the problem of transactional safety.

Very simply put, a unit of work is a collection of all repositories, it forces the repositories to share the same context, and it allows for the developer to directly commit/rollback the context for all repositories at the same time. A simple example:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    public readonly FooRepository FooRepository;
    public readonly BarRepository BarRepository;
    public readonly BazRepository BazRepository;

    private readonly MyContext _context;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        _context = new MyContext();

        this.FooRepository = new FooRepository(_context);
        this.BarRepository = new BarRepository(_context);
        this.BazRepository = new BazRepository(_context);
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And a simple usage example:

```
using (var uow = new UnitOfWork())
{
    uow.FooRepository.Add(myFoo);
    uow.BarRepository.Update(myBar);
    uow.BazRepository.Delete(myBaz);

    uow.Commit();
}
```

And now we have transactional safety. Either all three objects are handled in the database, or none of them are.

---

### But Entity Framework is a framework! (personal note)

Maybe you've noticed, maybe you haven't, but you should see strong similarities to EF's `DbContext` and the `UnitOfWork` I just created. They are essentially the same thing. They represent a single transaction to the database, and offer access to collections of all available entity types:

```
public class UnitOfWork
{
    public readonly FooRepository FooRepository;
    public readonly BarRepository BarRepository;
    public readonly BazRepository BazRepository;

    public void Commit() { }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public Set<Foo> Foos { get; private set; }
    public Set<Bar> Bars { get; private set; }
    public Set<Baz> Bazs { get; private set; }

    public int SaveChanges() { }
}
```

EF's `DbContext` satifies [the definition of what a unit of work is](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html):

> A Unit of Work keeps track of everything you do during a business transaction that can affect the database. When you're done, it figures out everything that needs to be done to alter the database as a result of your work.

**So why do we do this?** Well, simply put, because developers always try to abstract dependencies. We don't want the business layer to directly depend on EF. This is the exact same reason why you've been creating repositories in the first place: so that your business logic doesn't directly use EF.

But what's the point of it all? Why do we use EF, then anti-patterned repositories, and then an anti-anti-patterned unit of work to make it all workable? This costs so much effort. We have to manually write search filters instead of being able to innately rely on EF's ability to parse (pretty much) any lambda method we throw at it. **Why are we going through all this effort instead just to use EF in the way it's already intended to work out of the box?**

And I have to admit that I've had this question for a long time but I find little support for my opinion. If you allow me to soapbox for a moment; my opinion on the matter is that this is why EF is called Entity **Framework** and not Entity Library.
The difference between frameworks and libraries is often semantial and up for debate, but I think an agreeable line can be drawn [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/148759/952296):

> A library performs specific, well-defined operations.
>
> A framework is a skeleton where the application defines the "meat" of the operation by filling out the skeleton. The skeleton still has code to link up the parts but the most important work is done by the application.

This description of a framework fits with EF to a tee. It pretty much does the whole DB interaction for us, but it requires us to extend `DbContext` with the entities (and model configuration) that we expect EF to use.

We abstract dependencies (libraries) because we can, and because the benefit of doing so (swappability) far outweighs the drawback (effort required to implement the abstraction). But frameworks, the skeleton of a system, are not easily replaced because they cannot be easily abstracted. The effort is much greater than the likelihood of needing to replace the dependency, and thus it's no longer worth the effort to do so.

I think that in order to cut out a lot of boilerplating code, it would be beneficial to consider EF as a framework that we build the application around and cannot easily move away from (the same way we can for a library). This means that we can do away with the repositories and the unit of work altogether, as their only purpose is to give access to the features EF already has; and instead use EF directly and accept that its usage is an architectural choice that we do not implement with the intention of easily moving away from it.

This means we could cut out the repositories and unit of work, and instead have our business logic deal with the context directly. Notice how the business logic code hardly changes:

```
// OLD

using (var uow = new UnitOfWork())
{
    uow.FooRepository.Add(myFoo);
    uow.BarRepository.Update(myBar);
    uow.BazRepository.Delete(myBaz);

    uow.Commit();
}

// NEW

using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    db.Foos.Add(myFoo);
    db.Bars.Update(myBar);
    db.Bazs.Delete(myBaz);

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

---

> The issue is I keep reading people responding saying "well EF is already abstraction". Well that's great, and that's probably true, but then how would you use it without the repository pattern?

By using EF directly and no longer trying to abstract it behind a self-developed wall of repositories (and possibly a unit of work).

> For those that say otherwise, why would you say otherwise, what personally have you run into that made is necessary?

The answer is sort of a recapitulation of my experience with EF over the last 6 to 7 years. Basic repositories by themselves introduce more problems than they solve. There are advanced solutions that solve the problems introduced by basic repositories; but you do eventually reach a point where you start wondering if it's not better to simply choose to not use repositories so you don't have to spend the effort to get them to play nicely with EF.

Can they be made to play nicely with EF? Sure thing. Is it worth the effort to create all that abstraction? That very much depends on the likelihood of you moving away from EF (or using a datastore that's incompatible with EF).

Comment: "By using EF directly" can you explain, on a high-level, how would you implement such a solution? Simply injecting DbContext and write queries of of it as need be?

Comment: @Iztoksson: I haven't really focused on DI and its benefit are somewhat unrelated to the current topic. Yes, that is the approach I would take, using DI and direct queries. I'm well aware that it's a controversial suggestion to remove the repositories from in between, so I'm apprehensive of definitively agreeing here; but I do think that there are situations in which the effort simply is not worth the gains.

Comment: Of course everything is "it depends" and sometimes not worth the gains, but we're not talking about a specific scale of an application here, we're discussing a concept. I think that most of the time people forget the initial or the primary role of the repository which is to decouple or isolate database code and access from other layers. Simply injecting EF everywhere is a mess, a controller shouldn't have the knowledge to simply coin-up a query and fire it against the db.

Comment: @Iztoksson: I would still advocate for a BLL which consumes the context, not having EF used by just _any_ consumer. I'm not arguing against all abstractions, but only specifically the repository abstraction between BLL and context when dealing with EF. Also, you can still have your `MyContext` implement an `IMyContext` interface (which can include methods signatures like `SaveChanges`) and thus keep your `IMyContext` contract reasonably abstracted.

Comment: Yes, using BLL is a better approach however you can still inject the DbContext a lot into different service classes inside BLL. Another way of doing it is making a specific, for example, ClientService which serves up all the Client related data and now becomes a Repository. But now this gets injected everywhere (and a CardService and AccountService and CreditService etc.). Why not simply make a UnitOfWork with repositories inside, and pass this around, with the benefit of being able to switch the implementation to let's say Dapper when EF gets too slow.

Comment: @Iztoksson: You missed the core of my comment. You wouldn't be injecting, you would be injecting `IMyContext`. It just happens to be the case that the current concrete class tied to `IMyContext` also derives from `DbContext`, but that's not required. You can create a completely different `IMyContext` implementation which can be injected as well. And I also want to point out that my suggestion is strongly rooted in the assumption that you're likely not going to move away from EF and thus don't need to overly prepare for an easy transition.

Comment: @Iztoksson: I'm not saying your suggestion doesn't work. I'm simply questioning the effort required to get it all working. Where do you store multi-entity-type queries in a way that makes sense and that developers will all agree and be able to easily find it? Are you prepared to hand-write methods with custom filter attributes that you then have to translate to a lamba (assuming LINQ method syntax)? How many DTO classes and mappings are you going to have to write if you truly want to separate your DAL from your BLL? There is a lot of effort going into this, plus potential sources for bugs.

Comment: @Flater I am extremely happy with this answer, and I think Flater really posted something here that is going to help a lot of people, as well as , myself. My only reqret.... Asking this where code samples aren't as prevalent. But this explanation goes above and beyond, thanks dude.

Comment: outstanding work @Flater - don't know why there are only 5 upvotes.

Comment: > For the same example, you would have to launch 3 separate database queries... 
This is due to the not great example. Realistically you should have a LocationRepository that gets data about the locations.

Comment: @StingyJack: You're abstracting that into "location logic" because I just happen to have picked 3 examples that are locations. Your solution doesn't work if I rename the classes (e.g. Person/Car/Box), which means your solution is semantical (and situational), not technical (or reliably reusable).

Comment: I'm conglomerating it into location related data access, because thats an obvious grouping for those data points. Using them in an example like this instead of actual Person, Car, and Box classes makes the point you are trying to make very easy for others to dismiss.  I dont disagree with the usefulness of separation but having to manage code and get performance from the overall system means that sometimes these objects may cross via some PersonCarBox repository and that is OK to do.

Comment: @StingyJack: Sure, but for a sufficiently complex application you're going to end up with countless permutations (`FooBarRepository`, `FooBazRepository`, `BarBazRepository`, `FooBarBazBatRepository`, ...) which gets nonsensical the more permutations you need to add. Effectively, you're already going to end up with many small repositories, so moving to one-method-repositories (i.e. query objects) is not difficult, and it means you no longer need to spend time categorizing queries based on which entity types they all handle at the same time.

Comment: @StingyJack Take the example of a query which needs to be changed and will now involve more/less entities. Are you going to move it from one repo to another? So that means that a lot of classes who depend on this repo also need to change (or add) their injected dependency. That's a lot of work for one change. And in the end, the whole "this query belongs in that repo" is a pointless exercise in categorizing for no technical benefit. By using a query object, you don't have to move your method as your query object represents your query _regardless of which entity types are involved_.

Comment: The way I look at this is that the more code we as developers write the more chance for bugs and complexity/readability issues. So the code we do write better exist for a VERY good reason. With EF, the reasons for repository's is reduced to the point of questioning if it really gives you the same level of benefit than without EF.

Comment: So how can we write unit tests for our business methods without using some abstraction over EF, (and using `DbContext` directly in business codes)?

Comment: @Masoud: EF Core allows for an in-memory database, which enables fast and contained unit testing. I'm unsure if the same feature was also released for non-Core EF as I haven't used it since.

Answer (score 4):

Entity framework is not a full abstraction, only a partial one. It only abstracts away the querying of the data.

For example, what if you have an `Order` entity, but as your application grows, it becomes a performance bottleneck. Your DBA then suggests splitting it into two tables, `current_order` for orders that took place within the last 30 days, and `older_order` for everything else. To complicate things even further, to increase performance even further, you DBA makes the PK of `current_order` int16 and `older_order` int64 PK, so now the two tables representing a single entity don't even have the same schema.

To complicate things even further, some orders take more than 30 days to fulfill; how will Entity Framework abstract away this complexity? Hint: **It won't**, and unless you're using the repository pattern to abstract away data access, this change is about to make your code a mess.

What if you need to switch from Postgres to MongoDb? Opps, EF doesn't support MongoDB, there goes that abstraction.

The fact is, EF uses the Active Record Pattern, and so it might be fair to say that it doesn't provide data abstraction at all since it is directly linked to the datasource, and is merely a tool for simplifying data-querying.

Comment: I'm not sure how you came to the "complex order" point as part of the answer. Of course EF doesn't handle a particular application's business logic such as the categorization of orders. In either case, whether you use repositories or not, you're going to have to have an algorithm somewhere that is in charge of sorting the orders into old and new (or whatever categorization you prefer). How do repositories solve this, other than by performing the role of _literally any consumer of EF_ that would be able to handle the required order logic?

Comment: Very bad example IMHO because you're trying to **solve a "problem" in the wrong place**. You answer is to nicely ask you DBA to add a new `order` view and three SP to add/edit/remove orders. Few changes in your EF code and everything else won't be touched. About switching to MongoDB...yes yes, that's true. **How many times** you had to move from SQL Server to Mongo?! Not to mention that you can even drop EF and replace it with a repository which exposes the same syntax (if you wish so) but you'll do it only when you need it (not just in case...for something that probably won't ever happen)

Comment: Not to mention that EF is **NOT** _"...directly linked to the datasource..."_ bla bla bla. You have pretty powerful functions to perform pretty advanced mapping (including splitting data between multiple tables). Is it complex? Of course it is. Is it easier and faster than introducing an abstraction that 99% you won't need? Exercise for the reader. Are there cases where a repository is the right choice? Of course but it comes with a high price you can't blindly accept without a rigorous, solid, and well-done analysis...

Comment: 100% right. This is why EF gets abandoned at enterprise level

Comment: @Ewan what do you typically see at the enterprise level?

Comment: @MZawg situations too complicated for EF...

Comment: @Ewan I meant more like the technology used. Not the situation.

Comment: I have to agree with Adriano here. This example would and should be handled at the DB level. No reason to do this in the app code.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the Entity Framework Data Context class *IS* your Repository. And in fact, recently I'm moving away from EF all together. I build mostly web sites with an Angular front-end. And my WebAPIs are just a thin veneer over the datastore. They query my SQL databases using the new JSON support in SQL server. And directly ship that JSON to the client. No need for a stack of objects to be created and serialized for every single API request.
Think about what the use of a Repository means, functionally, in a single API request, and what is the benefit of doing it this way? Roughly:

1. Request comes in and .net creates an instance of your Controller and has to DI a Repository instance into it.
2. Your Repo instance most likely gets a DI created instance of your EF Data Context.
3. Your controller method is invoked and you run a LINQ query which creates a IQueryable instance.
4. That IQueryable is then returned from your method to .net which then materializes the IQueryable.
5. EF then maps that to a whole bunch of instances of your Entity Classes.
6. Then .net serializes those entity instances in memory.
7. Then .net starts writing the serialized data to the response stream.

All of those instances are sitting in memory for what? A few milliseconds? Its a total waist and there is no reason for all the complication and bloat. And don't get me started on all the extra methods people pollute their repositories with. For instance I need to search by last name. So now I'm going to add a GetByLastName method to the repository. Oh but the boss now wants to be able to search by first name, so do I refactor or add a GetByFirstName? And now he wants both. But I refactored GetByLastName as GetByFirstName. But now he wants to add zip code as an optional parameter. So, I learned my lesson on GetByLastName, so I'm going to add a GetByLastNameAndFirstNameAndZip method...

All of that could be avoided by treating EF as your Repository and just adding criteria to your LINQ query which resides right there in your API method.

Or, do what I do, and avoid both Repository and EF and query with FOR JSON. To do that I have a tiny service that is a mere abstraction over the ADO.Net classes that only has a GetScalar and a GetJSON method. That's all you really need.

Comment: A bit of an old question from me. But glad you answered to allow to me review it once again. I have in fact come into your line of thinking. Not really specifics, but while I’m sure EF, repository pattern, etc all have their place. To your point I’m finding project per project, more than not they require neither of them. Just as your ‘FOR JSON’ by passes this.

Comment: I'd argue that it is the `DbSet<T>` which is the repository, and that the context class acts as the unit of work which ties all the "repositories" together.